# How do I figure when an index was last used?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

In Postgres I can run a query against `pg_stat_user_indexes` table to verify whether an index was ever scanned or not. I have quite a few indexes that have 0 scans and have a few with less than 5 scans. I am considering a possibility of removing those indexes but I want to know when they were last used. Is there a way to find out when the last index scan happened for an index?

Comment: Hi, have you checked the explain?

Comment: Hello. I am not sure how `explain` can help me get the last index scanned date. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Try this: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
select....;  and paste the results here explain.depesz.com or here tatiyants.com/pev

Comment: in pg16. this problem seems solved. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/release-16.htm#RELEASE-16-MONITORING

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot find out when an index was last used. I recommend that you take the usage count now and again a month from now. Then see if the usage count has increased.

Don't hesitate to drop indexes that are rarely used, unless you are dealing with a data warehouse. Even if the occasional query can take longer, all data modifications on the table will become faster, which is a net win.

Answer (score 0):

It happens, that a index was once used, but there is no certainty that the index is still used. Then you need to recollect the statistics. Clear statistics in the database:

```
SELECT pg_stat_reset();
```

Now, if you run the query again to get statistics on the use of indexes, the table names will remain there, but all data about scans will be reset. You can continue to work — the database will again collect statistics and after some time it will be possible to identify unused indexes again.

[Source](https://dmitry-naumenko.medium.com/how-to-define-unused-indexes-in-postgresql-471da6f6f33f)